# PypeR suddenly stops working when two or more users use it

Tags: python, r, django, pyper

I am using Pyper as a way to connect  Python to R using Django framework ,I am using it in a way that i am running r script through pyper using r.run("source('"+path2script+"')").
But i am running into an issue where pyper suddenly stops when two or more users try to access it. I do not understand why it is happening and how pyper stops suddenly.
Also r script i am using performs lot of calculations. My idea is calculation is filling the r session and then pyper stops.

Can anybody help me with this. Thanks in advance.